# https redirect for every url doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, xenforo

I have an issue that came out after I have successfully transferred my website from a server to another (it's always the same url). Basically I have a forums created with xenforo that can be reached at `https://forums.mywebsite.com`.

Of course you can log in with your account and save username/password in the browser if needed. The problem is the following:

- With `https://forums.mywebsite.com` you are still logged
- With `http://forums.mywebsite.com` you have to login every time
- With `www.forums.mywebsite.com` you have to login every time

I guess that there is an issue with the cookies, because the cookies for the `https` work while the others not. My idea was to redirect every single url to an https url; so:

- With `https://forums.mywebsite.com` > no changes
- With `http://forums.mywebsite.com` > `https://forums.mywebsite.com`
- With `www.forums.mywebsite.com` > `https://forums.mywebsite.com`

I really need this and telling users to use only https is not a great solution because there always be someone that uses http or www. My idea was this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.forums.mywebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Anyway when I type www.forums.mywebsite.com I still don't get a redirect to https://forums.mywebsite.com. Do I have to change any config file?

---

I am editing [this](https://prnt.sc/jgh4q0)  .htaccess that can be found at the root of the system as you can see here (taken from WinSCP).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On my Xenforo board I require the same thing, redirect everything to https://example.com without www.

This is what I use:

```
#Redirect www and http
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Never had a problem with it like this.